# How do I get this scheme to work properly? what am i doing wrong?

Tags: scheme, racket, automata

```
(define first car)
(define rest cdr)

(define (ins lst ele)
  (if (not (mem lst ele)) (append lst (list ele)) lst)
)
```

when I call the function (ins 5'(2 10 -3)) it's supposed to add the 5 into the list and should return (5 2 10 -3) but I can't figure out what is going on. Can someone guide me?

I keep getting this error

```
mem: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

Comment: Hint: `cons`, not `append`

Comment: @Shawn that didn't work

Comment: Perhaps the function you think is called `mem` is called something else? [The Racket documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/) is probably useful here

Comment: As in `(cons ele lst)`. Figured `mem` was some function you had defined but didn't show, like in the original second part of your post (The edit improved the question a lot).

Comment: @Shawn ty for providing the append alternative but it still says error: mem is not defined.

Comment: There is no mem procedure. Maybe you wanted the member procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean:

```
(define first car)
(define rest cdr)

(define (ins lst ele)
  (if (not (member? ele lst)) (append lst (list ele)) lst))
```

### Or you define `mem` yourself

```
(define (mem lst ele)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((equal? ele (car lst)) #t)
        (else (mem (cdr lst) ele))))
```

With extra test:

```
(define (mem lst ele (test equal?))
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((test ele (car lst)) #t)
        (else (mem (cdr lst) ele test))))
```

And tail call recursion with recursive search within `lst`:

```
(define (mem* lst ele (test equal?) (acc #f))
  (cond ((null? lst) acc)
        ((list? (car lst)) (mem* (cdr lst) ele test (or acc (mem* (car lst) ele test))))
        ((test ele (car lst)) #t)
        (else (mem* (cdr lst) ele test acc))))
```

And after one of those you add:

```
(define first car)
(define rest cdr)

(define (ins lst ele)
  (if (not (mem ele lst)) (append lst (list ele)) lst))
```

Comment: none of these work it says either mem not defined and if i define mem it says ins not defined.

Comment: you obviously didn't put the definitions in the right order. Try the second part then. I mean't either you use the first version - it should work without giving any additional definition - IF you use `#lang racket` - but probably you don't use Racket? Which Scheme implementation you are using exactly?

Comment: I was anyway wondering, because `car` and `cdr` should be defined already in any normal Scheme implementation. Or are you using some limited teaching Scheme variant? (I guess so ...)